# sys.stdin python

Tags: python, stdin

```
import sys
for i in sys.stdin:
    print(i)
```

Объясните работу stdin! Насколько я понял stdin-пустой, пока пользователь не введет данные. Программа должна завершится а меня просят ввести данные. Почему?

Comment: Потому что она ждёт когда пользователь введёт данные

Comment: @andreymal т.е тут просят ввести данные и сразу же добавляет в stdin?

Comment: @сергейпушкаев print выводит в stdout. Чтобы завершилась нужно зевершить цикл for. Например добавив break после print(i)

Comment: Как я понял, мы рассматриваем вариант ввода с клавиатуры. Stdin не закрыт, поэтому программа ожидает ввода и будет продолжать обрабатывать входящие данные, пока не будет считан EOF (end of file), который означает, что ввод завершён. (Ctrl + D в Unix и Ctrl + Z в Windows, насчёт Винды не уверен, только что загуглил).